# Genetic Algorithm - Use of multiobjective function when optimising bushings in different degrees of freedom

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to find specific bushing values (one linear stiffness and one linear dampning parameter for each bushing) to solve a tracking problem. For each degree of freedom (DOF) I am including one bushing.

My initial simulations included a model with only one DoF for which the GA worked well. However as I am adding more complexity to the model by introducing more DoF I am not sure that using a single objective function is the best way forward.

For example:

I now have 3 DOF (axial displacement (tY), shear displacement (tX) and rotation (rZ) in the same plane) I am not sure if the GA is optimising the bushings for their respective DOF as I only have one fitness function.

Would a multiobjective GA be able to optimise:

Bushing tY for DOF tY based on a objective fuction for that DOF,
Bushing tX for DOF tX based on a seperate objective fuction for that DOF and
Bushing rZ for DOF rZ based on an  other seperate objective fuction for that DOF?

I am using Matlab R2017a and the ga function for the algorithm.

Thank you in advance for your help and assistance.

Best regards
Pavlos